# MySQL stored procedure cannot add values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GetCustomerLevel(p_barcode int)

BEGIN

DECLARE q1 int;

DECLARE q2 int;

DECLARE q3 int;

DECLARE total int;

SET total :=0;

SELECT SUM(adjustment_quantity) 
INTO q1 
FROM adjustment_inventory  
WHERE item_barcode = p_barcode 
GROUP BY adjustment_quantity;

SELECT SUM(opening_stock) 
INTO q2 
FROM openingstock
WHERE item_barcode = p_barcode 
GROUP BY opening_stock;

SELECT SUM(inwardquantity) 
INTO q3
FROM inwardmaster 
WHERE item_barcode = p_barcode 
GROUP BY inwardquantity;

IF q1 IS NULL THEN

    SET q1 := 0;

END IF;

IF q2 IS NULL THEN

    SET q2 := 0;

END IF;

IF q3 IS NULL THEN

    SET q3 := 0;

END IF;

SELECT q1;
SELECT q2;
SELECT q3;
SELECT q1+q2+q3;
END$$
```

It's return wrong answer every time. For example q1=100 q2=200 q3=100 it returns 100

Comment: If you run them seperatly, wouldn't those queries return more than 1 value? Since each one is grouped by what they SUM. It seems you should remove the GROUP BY's.  And you could use COALESCE to turn NULL to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. but your code also give the wrong answer ... When my values are q1=-500 q2=500 q3=15000 but total is 15000 i d'not know  why it's happened. My old code also give the same wrong answer 15000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to use stored procedure for this

```
set @barcode = '1234';

select 
    coalesce((
      SELECT sum(coalesce(adjustment_quantity,0)) 
      FROM adjustment_inventory 
      WHERE item_barcode = @p_barcode
    ),0) + 
    coalesce((
      SELECT sum(opening_stock) 
      FROM openingstock
      WHERE item_barcode = @p_barcode
    ), 0) + 
    coalesce((
      SELECT 
      sum(coalesce(inwardquantity,0))
      FROM inwardmaster WHERE item_barcode = @p_barcode
    ), 0) res
From Dual
;
```

If you really want to use procedure then check the code below

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCustomerLevel(p_barcode int)
BEGIN
  DECLARE q1 int;
  DECLARE q2 int;
  DECLARE q3 int;
  DECLARE total int;
SET total :=0;
  SELECT coalesce(sum(adjustment_quantity), 0) INTO q1 FROM adjustment_inventory WHERE item_barcode = p_barcode;
  SELECT coalesce(sum(opening_stock), 0) INTO q2 FROM openingstockWHERE item_barcode = p_barcode;
  SELECT coalesce(sum(inwardquantity), 0) INTO q3 FROM inwardmaster WHERE item_barcode = p_barcode;

  SELECT q1;
  SELECT q2;
  SELECT q3;

  set total = q1+q2+q3;

  SELECT total;
END$$
```